# JSON Parser Element not found

Tags: c#, json, json.net, linq-to-objects

This is my JSON

```
{
   "State of Origin 2014":{
      "1471137":{
         "EventID":1471137,
         "ParentEventID":1471074,
         "MainEvent":"State Of Origin Series 2014",
         "Competitors":{
            "ActiveCompetitors":3,
            "Competitors":[
               {
                  "Team":"New South Wales (2 - 1)",
                  "Win":"2.15",

               },
               {
                  "Team":"New South Wales (3 - 0)",
                  "Win":"3.05",

               },
               {
                  "Team":"Queensland (2 - 1)",
                  "Win":"3.30",

               }
            ],
            "TotalCompetitors":3,
            "HasWinOdds":true
         },
         "EventStatus":"Open",
         "IsSuspended":false,
         "AllowBets":true
      },
      "3269132":{
         "EventID":3269132,
         "ParentEventID":0,
         "MainEvent":"New South Wales v Queensland",
         "Competitors":{
            "Margin1Low":1,
            "Competitors":[
               {
                  "Name":"New South Wales",
                  "Win":"1.60",

               },
               {
                  "Name":"Queensland",
                  "Win":"2.35",

               }
            ],
            "HasWinOdds":true,
            "TotalOddsColumns":2,
            "MarketCount":1,
            "PerformVideo":false
         },
         "EventStatus":"Open",
         "IsSuspended":false,
         "AllowBets":true
      }
   }
}
```

I am using JSON.Net and everything is working fine but in some of my data some element fields are missing for example i am getting Team element inside Competitors as

```
 Teams = from JObject comps in value["Competitors"]["Competitors"]
                       select (string)comps["Team"]
```

But in some data Team element is missing and i want to grap Name Element so i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error.

This is my code

```
    var query =
       from JProperty ev in obj.AsJEnumerable()
       from JProperty evid in ev.Value.AsJEnumerable()
       let value = (JObject)evid.Value
       select new Person
       {
           EventID = (string)value["EventID"],
           Description = (string)value["MainEvent"],
           OutcomeDateTime = (string)value["OutcomeDateTime"],
           EventStatus = (string)value["EventStatus"],
           Teams = from JObject comps in value["Competitors"]["Competitors"]
               select (string)comps["Team"]

       };

    foreach (var b in query)
    {

        string description = b.Description;
        string OutcomeDateTime = b.OutcomeDateTime;
        IEnumerable<string> _team = b.Teams;
        foreach (var teams in _team)
        {

            string team = teams.ToString();


        }
        Console.WriteLine(description);
        Console.WriteLine(OutcomeDateTime);


    }
```

How can i get Name element value if Team element does not exist ?

Comment: if Team doesnt exist, then where does the name come from? Can you update your example JSON, to show this case?

Comment: can you check ["Competitors"]["Competitors"] inside in the first data you can see team element but in the second data there is no team data and instead there is a Name element

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your json to concrete classes

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,RootObject>>>(json);
```

---

```
public class Competitor
{
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string Win { get; set; }
}

public class CompetitorsClass
{
    public int ActiveCompetitors { get; set; }
    public List<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }
    public int TotalCompetitors { get; set; }
    public bool HasWinOdds { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int ParentEventID { get; set; }
    public string MainEvent { get; set; }
    public CompetitorsClass Competitors { get; set; }
    public string EventStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
    public bool AllowBets { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: What is `OutcomeDateTime`? there is no such field in your json.

Comment: sorry i am new to C# what do you mean by deserialize to concrete classes.Can i place some kind of condition in my code for example if Team element is not present then print Name element value something like that?

Comment: @user3750312 How about copying&pasting above code and playing a little bit with it?

Comment: i have tried something like this  foreach ( Dictionary<string, RootObject> eachItem in obj2) but i am getting an error

Comment: `eachItem` is a *KeyValuePair*, just write `var eachItem` insteaof `Dictionary<string, RootObject> eachItem`. VS editor will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work. Use the null-coalescing operator to grab "Name" if "Team" is null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

```
Teams = from JObject comps in value["Competitors"]["Competitors"]
                        select (string)comps["Team"] ?? (string)comps["Name"]
```